# Prove that set of columns of an incidence matrix M with integral values mod 2 are linearly independent iff the corresponding set of edges are acyclic

Tags: graph-theory, linear-independence

This is a question from CLRS 3E, 16-3a.

> Argue that a set of columns of an incident Matrix M is linearly independent over the field of integers modulo 2 if and only if the corresponding set of edges is acyclic.

Graph used in this question is undirected. What really bugs me in this question is that, Let's say I have a graph with 3 vertices A, B & C with 3 edges x, y & z such that A--x--B, B--y--C & C--z--A. Which gives me the following Incidence Matrix:

|  | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 1 |

The columns of this matrix are linearly independent too since x=0 is the only solution to Mx=0. The questions asks the reader to prove that linear independence should only be possible when there is no cycle but in this case there is a cycle and it's still independent?

I have seen the answer posted at: [Prove that columns of incidence matrix of tree are linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731523/prove-that-columns-of-incidence-matrix-of-tree-are-linearly-independent)
but that doesn't clear my doubt. Since the question uses the phrase if and only if, shouldn't it also imply that in case of a cycle it will always be dependent?

Comment: I think it holds when the graph is undirected. In that case, the matrix would be a matrix of 1s, so its columns are not independent and, indeed, the graph has a cycle

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Here, I am talking about an undirected graph with the incident matrix being full of 1s. In this graph with a cycle, the columns come out independent. Am I missing something?

Comment: The columns of a matrix full of 1s are dependent

Comment: Indeed the columns of this matrix are linearly independant when working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}.$ However, the statement deals with the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ of integers modulo $2$. Over this field, the sum of the three columns is null.